# Adding data files to SBT project

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to add a data file or a configuration file along with my application (such as sample.conf). This file should be available to user so that he/she can edit the sample configuration to further customize the application.

How can I add such files to my project such that

1. This file becomes part of distributable, and
2. How can I link it in my source documentation, so that its purpose can be doucmented, and
3. This is file is goes into a special directory (such as conf)

Or is there any such predefined task available.

Comment: Did you try sbt native packager? https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SBT Native Packager provides support for doing what you want, though you'll have to dig through the docs a bit. The `universal` packager is probably the best approach for you.

http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/

Comment: sbt-native-packager solves these issues. I can use src/universal to add more files. Checking with akkaAppPackaging if it supports it as well.

Comment: sbt native packager works perfect. It works out of the box! with 1.0.0 (RC) it is very convenient to use enablePlugins.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the typesafehub/config https://github.com/typesafehub/config project. It uses the HOCON format (Human Optimized Config Object Notation).

Comment: This is not what I intend to know. I would like to deliver a config file (or any file for that matter) along with my application.